# Timeline of all changes to piece of code to revert back

Tags: python, revision-history

Is there anyway i can see the history of all the changes which i have made over a period of time. Such as if i am working on a piece of code and over time i had taken a wrong direction and now the code is too complex or unreadable, if at this point i could see what the code was at an earlier stage so i can revert back to that code and start again from. A system which would perhaps give a timeline of all the changes?

I would prefer a `opensource system` which could accomplish this but it could be paid too.

Comment: You should use something like git

Comment: Some editors also keep the change history

Comment: Could you give an example of a python editor which can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git is a tool made for that purpose.